# saving PDF/word/jpeg files as image in sql server database

Tags: sql-server, pdf, save

I am working on an existing database structure.  The database has a field to store PDF/Word/Jpeg files as images.  Unfortunately I cannot change the database field format.

I am able to successfully read the pdf stored as image and display the pdf file, but cannot get to insert the image in database.  I tried different version from many sites, but could not get it to work.

Here is my current code

```
    Dim sql As String
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim sqlquery As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim sqlconn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Try
        sqlconn.ConnectionString = dbConnectStr1
        sqlquery.Connection = sqlconn
        sqlconn.Open()
        For cnt1 = 0 To dgv1.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim fInfo As New FileInfo(dgv1.Rows(cnt1).Cells(3).Value)
            Dim numBytes As Long = fInfo.Length
            Dim fStream As New FileStream(dgv1.Rows(cnt1).Cells(3).Value, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            Dim br As New BinaryReader(fStream)
            Dim data As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(CInt(numBytes))
            br.Close()
            fStream.Close()
            sql = "INSERT INTO " & attachmentTbl & " (DocID, DocName, DocType, DocFile, DocLength) " &
            "VALUES ('" & dgv1.Rows(cnt1).Cells(0).Value & "', '" & dgv1.Rows(cnt1).Cells(1).Value & "', '" & dgv1.Rows(cnt1).Cells(2).Value & "', "  data  ", " & numBytes & ")"
            sqlquery.CommandText = sql
            '"VALUES (@DocID, @DocName, @DocType, @DocFile, @DocLength)"

            'sqlquery.OleDbParameter.Add(New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@DocID", dgv1.Rows(cnt1).Cells(0).Value))
            'sqlquery.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@DocName", dgv1.Rows(cnt1).Cells(1).Value))
            'sqlquery.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@DocType", dgv1.Rows(cnt1).Cells(2).Value))
            'sqlquery.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@DocFile", data))
            'sqlquery.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@DoDocLength", numBytes))
            'sqlquery.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
        sqlconn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        errorFlag = True
        MessageBox.Show("Error#060 " & ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try
```

Also, Is there a way to get the file type displayed in windows explorer.  I.e. for .pdf file the display with would "adobe acrobat document" .xls file  would be "Microsoft excel worksheet"

I tried using the below code but I don't get the above stuff

```
    extn = Path.GetExtension(txtFileName.Text)
    Dim regKey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(extn)
    If Not regKey Is Nothing Then
        Dim ct As Object = regKey.GetValue("Content Type")
        If Not ct Is Nothing Then
            extn = ct.ToString()
        End If
    End If
```

Appreicate your help.

Comment: When you say it isn't working, are you getting an error? Why are you using OleDb? For better SQL Server performance in .NET, use SqlClient. The commented code should explicitly specify the appropriate SqlDbType and max length for each parameter.

Comment: Mr. Dan, thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Dan, I had no plan of programing when I started my current job about 1.5 year ago.  I used to be a mainframe programmer in the 90s and currently work in finance.  Long story short to make my life easier I started programming.  Oledb is left when I was using access database.  I did not know anybetter about sqlclient.  Thanks for your pointer.

Comment: Dan... You are the best... using sqlclient fixed the problem.... hip hip hurray... thanks

Comment: Managed providers are always best in .NET code, although you will need to resort to OleDb or ODBC if the database vendor doesn't supply one. You should have been able to get it working with OleDb too but there is no good reason need to go there.